# Difference between an 'Abstract' and an 'Introduction' in a feature article?

Tags: writing-advice

I have to write a feature article for school. However, I'm confused how an abstract [a summary of my points] is different to an intro [Where you outline the points you're going to be elaborating in the body paragraphs]

Original Example:

Title:  **Single Mothers, ‘the damaged goods’ of society?**

Abstract:

`They’re the unrepresented minorities in our society. Victims of social prejudice, these women are marginalised in media as a whole different class of people. They’re irresponsible sluts; ‘the damaged goods’. They’re woefully incapable of raising a baby with morals. They’re dependent; Work-shy-unambitious class of beings who only live off well-fare. Sadly, they’re the Single Mothers of our society.`

Introduction:
Confused! Shouldn't my 'abstract' text be my introduction paragraph?!

UPDATE: Remember that I am NOT writing a research paper, rather, a persuasive article, when writing your answers please.

Comment: This is General Reference. Any decent dictionary would clearly define the two different usages.

Comment: This question would be better asked at writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract is a paragraph which summarizes each of the main parts of the paper (introduction, theory, application, conclusion) in a sentence or two.

The introduction sets the scene for the paper, presenting the problem at hand, some previous relevant work, and maybe the reasons for doing the investigation.